# Injecting custom logger into Specflow framework when using NUnit

Tags: dependency-injection, nunit, specflow

Is there a way to inject custom logger into Specflow framework to capture beginnings and ends of the steps when using NUnit, or any other supported testing framework apart from XUnit? This [help page](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Integrations/xUnit.html) (and [Github issue](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/pull/689)) shows that with XUnit you can use its `ITestOutputHelper` to inject custom logger that would gather in the right order both Specflow logging as well as any additional logging that is present in steps.

I am using Context Injection and dependency injection with Autofac to setup all the parts of the test framework. And I understand how to inject any type of logger into `Binding` classes.
I wonder if it is possible to adapt current standard `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T>` to be used for Specflow, step definitions, and other parts of the framework, so that it captures the full flow of the scenario. Or should I write Before/After hooks to get Scenario/Step definitions.

Comment: Can you explain more about why this is desirable? This might be something you can capture with the NUnit console runner.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, When Specflow test runs it outputs messages to the NUnit log when step starts and when it completes. Because I am doing E2E testing for a fairly complex system, I want to put logging into each framework component that is used by steps, and would like to see these message for each step internals between step start/finishing messages produced by Specflow. I might be able able to achieve something close by using NUnit's `TestContext.Progress` methods, but it only writes to console, as I understand. But I also would like to output these logs to the file.